# How to add the content of a read only textbox to a email body?

Tags: c#, winforms, email, textbox

I have a textbox where it is read-only property enabled and has a text typed in the properties. I want to add the content of a read-only textbox into the body of an email. However the content of the textbox doesn't display in the body of the email received.

Is it possible?

```
private void notifyBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string currentTime = DateTime.Now.ToString();

    // Get the name of the student from the TextBox
    string nameStudent = studName.Text;  

    // Email configuration
    string senderEmail = "***************@gmail.com";
    string recipientEmail = "***************@gmail.com";
    string subject = "Memorandum of Agreement Submission";
    string body = "Klasmeyt " + nameStudent + "has submitted his memorandum of agreement document. \nTime: " + currentTime;

    // SMTP configuration
    string smtpAddress = "smtp.gmail.com";
    int portNumber = 587; // Or your SMTP port
    bool enableSSL = true;
    string emailFrom = "***************@gmail.com";
    string password = "***************";

    // Create SMTP client
    using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
    {
        mail.From = new MailAddress(emailFrom);
        mail.To.Add(recipientEmail);
        mail.Subject = subject;
        mail.Body = body;

        // Configure SMTP client
        using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(smtpAddress, portNumber))
        {
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(emailFrom, password);
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;

            try
            {
                // Send email
                smtp.Send(mail);
                MessageBox.Show("Notification email sent successfully.", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Failed to send notification email. Error: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Tutorial: Learn to debug C# code using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger). Add a breakpoint on the line `string senderEmail = ...` and see what `nameStudent` contains. We cannot debug your code.

Comment: You have looked at the eml source at the receiving end here? If the client does not expect plaintext but defaults to html it will just show nothing even if the mail contains plaintext.

Comment: I tried the breakpoint it contains only "" or blank.. I don't know why but it contains some text in the text property

Comment: If you set the the breakpoint on the line following the line `string nameStudent = studName.Text;` and `nameStudent` is empty then the `Text` property of the textbox is empty as well. Are you confusing textboxes? Btw., it is often easier to use WinForms Data Binding instead of accessing the controls directly.

Comment: On start up or somewhere in the code you set the textbox.text blank. Read-only only effect the user interface. Does the text box can be seen in the form if so has the text in it?